# Bios enable disable buttons are not clickable

Tags: bios, netbios, bioservices, sysbios, biosppy

I want to enable virtualization on my thinkpad t450 but the enable/disable botton are not clickable  please what is the problem, is there any way or anything I can do to click the buttons and enable virtualization? And I also check the CPU requirements it supports virtualization

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.